# How to hide Core Data model in app using Static Library (iOS)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, core-data, ios

I develop Static Library in XCode. I want to use Core Data by using Core Data model.

How I can hide Core Data model file in app, that is using Static Library. I don't want anybody to be able to see data base scheme. The same time, when developer will use some methods that depends on Core Data model, everyhting will work.

Thanks for help! Cheers!

Bartosz

Comment: possible duplicate of [core data in a static library for the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711586/core-data-in-a-static-library-for-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a similar question and I found my answer here [core data in a static library for the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711586/core-data-in-a-static-library-for-the-iphone).

Maybe it will be helpful for you.