# core data in a ios static library

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data, static-libraries

I created a static library for iOS. The library uses core data to store some objects fetched from the internet.
When I try to use my library in a standard iOS project, it seems like it can't create any instances of core data entities. I have the following error :

```
-[NSManagedObject initWithDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e5d4e0 

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject initWithDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e5d4e0'
```

initWithDictionary is actually a method I call on a core data entity object.

Then I tried to create the managed object model out of the library like shown here : [core data in a static library for the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711586/core-data-in-a-static-library-for-the-iphone)

```
NSMutableSet *allBundles = [[[NSMutableSet alloc] init] autorelease];
[allBundles addObjectsFromArray: [NSBundle allBundles]];
[allBundles addObjectsFromArray: [NSBundle allFrameworks]];
managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles: [allBundles allObjects]];
```

OR

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];  
managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
```

but it didn't work. I have the following error when I try to instantiate a class of my library giving  it the managed object model :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LauncherViewController initWithNibName:managedObjectModel:andKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b94db0'
```

If I try this : [core data in a static library for the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711586/core-data-in-a-static-library-for-the-iphone/4610584#4610584) , I get this error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

Please help me, I really don't know what to do anymore...

Comment: Did you try to add '-all_load -ObjC' on the 'Other Linker Flags' section?

Comment: Yes I did but it doesn't change anything...