# Trigger.io Custom Module & ForgeInspector

Tags: ios, xcode, trigger.io

Our project has a requirement to use user tracking from SOMO (somoglobal.com), and given this module doesn't exist in Trigger, we're trying to build our own bespoke module so we can load the tracking `API` and send Events from the trigger app using a custom forge.somo object.

I've followed the documentation on creating custom modules, and so far it's fairly straightforward. However, the SOMO plugin requires a couple of files to be part of the module and this is where I'm stumbling, getting errors in the `ForgeInspector` app when testing.

In the below screenshot, I've highlighted the 3rd party files added to the `ForgeModule` project; a `xcdatamodeld` file to the `Compile Sources`, a `.pem` to `ForgeModule`'s bundle resources., and the .a added to the libraries. However, when I run `ForgeInspector` to test my module is working, I get errors that I have pinpointed to the `xcdatamodeld` & `.pem` files (with the PEM, ForgeInspector complains that it cannot find the file) If I manually edit the ForgeInspector project, adding these files to that skeleton, everything seems to work fine.

My understanding is I cannot/shouldn't edit ForgeInspector, given it represents the untouchable main Trigger project - is there a way around this? Feels like a scoping issue, but I would have thought anything in the sub-project would be visible to the parent, so I'm hoping I'm just displaying my relative inexperience with iOS / xcode development :-)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding to the ForgeInspector, just to see what happens?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711586/core-data-in-a-static-library-for-the-iphone