# Create inheritable core data model in a static library

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, inheritance, core-data

I am working on a project that has a static library shippable. The static library uses core data and I succeeded to compile my core data model into a separate bundle and ship the bundle with the library as it is described for example here: [core data in a static library for the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711586/core-data-in-a-static-library-for-the-iphone).

Now my problem is that I would like to make the core data entities in the data model of the library inheritable. Thus the user could extend these entities, adding his own attributes and relationships to my base entities via [core data inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdMOM.html). How could I achieve this considering that due version control purposes or package managers (I use cocoapods for the static library) it is better not to let the user modify the original core data model?

My current solution is to ship the original data model as a "template" and ask the users of the library to create a copy of it, extend it, and include *only* the extended data model and not the original one. But this feels somehow unprofessional and creates a mess for the users. Are there any other solutions that I am not aware of?