# How to add momd(managed object model) into ios framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, ios-frameworks

I am trying to convert my ios app(XYZ) into framework(XYZ.framework) so that it can be included in other ios applications. Went through below links and able to develop a framework.

LINK1:[LINK1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios)

LINK2:[LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711586/core-data-in-a-static-library-for-the-iphone)

But when i include my framework in other apps and try to compile for **first time** , xcode is throwing error **"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity."**.  I followed below steps and get rid of this error.

**STEP1:** Added XYZ.framework in other app and compiled for **first time**, but xcode gave error mentioned above.

**STEP2:** Added XYZ.momd(**by drag and drop**) along with XYZ.framework in other application. Compiled it and Xcode didn't throw any error.

**STEP3:** Removed XYZ.momd from  other application and compiled it. Xcode didn't throw any error!!!!

Should i give XYZ.momd along with XYZ.framework while distributing XYZ.framework, so that XYZ.momd can be included in other applications? I googled, but didn't get how to add momd inside framework and include it in other applications.

Comment: Hi did you figure it out?

Comment: I ended up implementing model by hand. Check this blog post: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/creating-a-coredata-model-in-code/