# Embed Core Data into a Static Library

Tags: ios, core-data, static-libraries

I am trying to embed a core data model into a static library or a framework. I have stumbled upon a few tutorials and SO questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711586/core-data-in-a-static-library-for-the-iphone). The process is to create a bundle target where you can embed the core data model file.

This is working fine, but it doesn't seem good enough for me. I have noticed that [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?hl=fr#headers) have implemented a static library that uses core data and all you have to add is headers and the .a file.

So my question is, how can we embed core data in a static library without having a bundle, just like Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the model in code by instantiating instances of `NSEntityDescription`, `NSPropertyDescription` etc. This involves a lot of boiler plate code but it is relatively straight forward.

An alternative, which I can't recommend but will mention, is to include the ManageObjectModel in the binary in some form. It can then be extract to a temporary folder and read as per normal. ([Embedding Resource Files in a Cocoa Foundation Command Line Tool](http://mentalfaculty.tumblr.com/post/71839659710/embedding-resource-files-in-a-cocoa-foundation-command))

Comment: Great, I hadn't actually realized that the `NSManagedObjectContext` was created at runtime with the compiled model file.