# Creating ManagetObjectModel in SDK development returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, sdk

I try to add CoreData in my SDK project, but

> NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"LSCmsModel"
>   withExtension:@"momd"];

always returns nil. I think it connected with differences in path for SDK and project which uses this SDK. But how to resolve it?

Comment: delete your LSCmsModel file and create new file then try it.

Comment: Have you tried it in Framework development? It doesn't work in my case :(

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711586/core-data-in-a-static-library-for-the-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, you get the app bundle. If you're developing a framework, that's not the framework bundle, so it won't find files in the framework.

Within a framework, you need to use either `bundleWithIdentifier:` or `bundleForClass:` to look up the framework bundle.

Comment: Yes, bundleForClass: saved me!