# Creating static library with CoreData in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, static-libraries, swift-framework

I am trying to create CoreDataKit using a static library.

It contains:

1. xcdatamodel or model file
2. NSManagedObject or Entity (

Since static library can have only objects files hence model file can't be part of static library.

To make it happen I created separate bundle having only model file and copied this bundle to my xcode project using this link ( [core data in a static library for the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711586/core-data-in-a-static-library-for-the-iphone))

Now, while loading Person entity

```
let personEntity = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context) as! Person
```

I got below error:

```
Unable to load class named 'MyStaticLibraryModels.Person' for entity 'Person'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
```

and exception:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSManagedObject_Person_' (0x600000243b40) to 'ONCoreDataKit.Person' (0x105d71a68).
```

The other approach could be to use framework which can contain model file and can be dynamically loaded.

Since loading dynamic framework can take some extra time I am interested in creating static library for faster access.

Comment: At a rough guess, you might have packed the model up in the bundle, but this doesn't automatically result in it getting copied into the build folder

Comment: I guess I am able to get model in build folder because following is working:   lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {

        let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyStaticLibraryModels", ofType: "bundle")
        let staticLibBundle = Bundle(path: url!)
        let modelURL = staticLibBundle!.url(forResource: "Model", withExtension: "mom")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
    }()

Comment: I am guessing since since model is now part of the main bundle and I am excessing Person from my "CoreDataKit" it's not able to get the Person entity.